# MPAndroidChart - How to change color of value?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How to change color of value's which I painted red ? I used `setValueTextColor` but it didn't work. 
It is still black

```
LineDataSet d1 = new LineDataSet(e1, entityList.get(i).getName());
d1.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 83));
sets.add(d1);
LineData cd = new LineData(dateList, sets);
cd.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(223, 83, 83));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d1.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 83));` 
is meant for the highlighting values within the graph.

The things that are underlined are `YAxis left and right`, `XAxis`, and `Legend`

For each of them you need to set the text color to get the desired effect.

Now to get the reference of them you need the chart object:

```
YAxis yAxisRight = mChart.getAxisRight();
YAxis yAxisLeft = mChart.getAxisLeft();
XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
```

and set the color for each of them by calling `setTextColor(int color)` method.

You can find this in the [official documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki) as well.